# Create matrix from two columns where one is column index and the other is value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns: one integer column and one with numeric values. I need to turn this into a matrix whereby all the values are zero except for when the column index matches the integer in the first column, in which case the value should be equal to the numeric value.

So for example,

```
int   num
  3   9.3
  2   2.2
  7   0.8
```

would become

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] 
[1,]    0    0  9.3    0   0    0    0
[2,]    0  2.2    0    0   0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0   0    0  0.8
```

I'm sure this is simple but I haven't had much luck. I know it would be possible with for loops but trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialise a matrix of only 0s and then fill in your values for each row using *matrix subsetting*:

```
out <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = max(df$int))
out[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$int)] <- df$num

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    0  0.0  9.3    0    0    0  0.0
# [2,]    0  2.2  0.0    0    0    0  0.0
# [3,]    0  0.0  0.0    0    0    0  0.8
```

Reproducible data

```
df <- data.frame(int = c(3L, 2L, 7L), num = c(9.3, 2.2, 0.8))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could expand the sequence from 1 to `int` part and  get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>%
  complete(int = 1:int, fill = list(num = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = int, values_from = num, values_fill = 0)

#     id   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0   0     9.3     0     0     0   0  
#2     2     0   2.2   0       0     0     0   0  
#3     3     0   0     0       0     0     0   0.8
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(int = c(3L, 2L, 7L), num = c(9.3, 2.2, 0.8)), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```